# Delete relationship with Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: java, spring, entity, relationship, spring-data-neo4j

I use SDN 4 (v4.2.1), Spring boot (1.5.2), Neo4j (v3.1.0) and I can't delete a simple relationship with the save () method.

```
@NodeEntity
public class A extends MyModel {

    @Relationship(type="link")
    private B b;

    //Getters and setters
}

@NodeEntity
public class B extends MyModel {

    @Relationship(type="link", direction=Relationship.INCOMING)
    private List<A> as;

    //Getters and setters
}

public interface ARepository implements GraphRepository<A> {

}

public interface BRepository implements GraphRepository<B> {

}

//Create relationship
A a a = ...;
B b = ...;
a.setB(b);
a = aRepository.save(a); // works
//Delete relationship
a.setB(null);
aRepository.save(a); // Not works
```

How do I succeed in removing the relationship in A and B ?

**EDIT**

Thank you for the answer.

And how to do it since validating a form.

```
@PostMapping(FORM)
public String form(@Valid @ModelAttribute("object") A a, BindingResult result, Model model, RedirectAttributes att, HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.info("/form");
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return form(model, a, request);
    }
    try {
        // a.getB() is null and a.getId() isn't null
        a = aService.save(a); // a.getB() isn't delete
        if (a.getId() == null)
            att.addFlashAttribute(MSG, a.getName() + " : create !");
        else
            att.addFlashAttribute(MSG, a.getName() + " : modify !");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        model.addAttribute(MSG, e.getMessage());
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return form(model, a, request);
    }
    return redirect(LISTE);
}
```

Here, my object is not in the session but the id was filled by spring mvc.
And b was selected by a drop-down list.

Comment: have you wrapped your atomic sequence of calls with @Transactional?

Comment: Yes, I use @Transactional on my method.

Comment: This should definitely work. Can you please raise a ticket here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH. If you have a code sample either as a zip or on github that we can replicate that would help a lot.

Comment: Ok. the repo : https://github.com/fichestrati/neo4j-test

Comment: It works with version spring data 4.1.8 and spring boot 1.4.5. Why ?

Comment: @RidgeIdylle I am facing the same problem. doesn't save updated node to the graph when deleting a relationship. have you figure out any solution please?

Answer (score 2):

The code you have defined above is not the same as the project:

```
@Transactional
public void test() {
    A a = new A();
    a.setName("a1");
    B b = new B();
    b.setName("b1");
    a.setB(b);
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println("id : "+a.getId());
    A a2 = aRepo.save(a);
    System.out.println(a2);
    Long id = a2.getId();
    System.out.println("id : "+id);

    A a3 = new A();
    a3.setId(id);
    a3.setName("a2");
    System.out.println(a3);
    aRepo.save(a3);
    System.out.println(aRepo.findOne(id)); // b must be null
}
```

There are a lot of things going on here so let's try and break it down first.

1. A new `A` is created with a `B` associated with it in variable `a`.
2. `a` is then saved to the database and a copy of `a` is returned as `a2`. At this stage both `a` and `a2` will have the same internal graph id  set (`a.id == a2.id`)
3. A new object called `a3` is created. The internal graph id from the previous step is set on `a3` (aka `@GraphId`) and it is saved to the database with no `B` reference.
4. An `A` is retrieved from the database that has the same `id` as `a2`.

Let's go through and see what is happening under the covers in each step.

1. There is no interaction with the OGM/SDN yet.
2. At this point `a` and it's `B` reference are saved to the database. The cache in the OGM/SDN now holds `a` with a link to `b` along with the database assigned internal Neo4j ID (which is saved in the `id` field of each object). A reference copy of `a` is assigned to `a2`.
3. At this point there is no interaction with the OGM/SDN. This new object is not managed by the OGM until `save()` is called. At this point things become undefined. By trying to set the internal id on the object the OGM discards this as it's not "attached" and instead uses the cached value in the `Session`.

It is important to note that one should never really change the value of `@GraphId`. In fact it really should never have been exposed design wise as it's not a mutable property.

To fix your issue, simply use the retrieved value form the session rather than instantiating a new object and trying to associate state from a previous call.

Comment: I changed the sample code in github and it still doesn't work. And it works with SDN 4.1.8.

Comment: This looks to be a bug in Spring Boot. I have raised an issue with the Spring Boot team: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8587

Comment: @RidgeIdylle SDN 4.1.8 with or without spring-boot (and which boot version)

Comment: Spring boot 1.4.5 with SDN 4.1.8

Comment: The repo with Spring Boot 1.4.5. https://github.com/fichestrati/neo4j-test/tree/with-spring-boot-1.4.5

Comment: This looks like it's going to be fixed in Spring Boot 1.5.3.

Comment: For now you can just add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to your application and it should all work again.